# Run python script repeatedly after execution, but with different input parameters

Tags: python, download, directory, repeat

Can anyone help me - which packages should I use to:

a) repeat my code n times after the download is finished, but with different input parameters (date range)

b)save the results of each month (this will be my date range) in separate folders

This is my code (based on https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sentinelsat):

```
import sys
from sentinelsat.sentinel import SentinelAPI, read_geojson, geojson_to_wkt
api = SentinelAPI('username', 'password', 'https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus')
args = sys.argv

# search by polygon, time, and SciHub query keywords
footprint = geojson_to_wkt(read_geojson('Hrvatska_sentinel.geojson'))
products = api.query(footprint,
                     date = (args[1], args[2]),
                     platformname = 'Sentinel-2',
                     producttype = 'S2MSI2Ap',
                     cloudcoverpercentage = (0,99))

# download all results from the search
print(products)
api.download_all(products)
```

Comment: You have 2 arguments, do they follow a pattern? If yes, you could have a bash script which has a loop to generate the arguments and run your python script with those arguments.

Comment: Put the code inside a loop (while or for) and change the paramenters after every execution. To fully automate this, get the parameters from a file.